# How can I do this query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have this tables:

> **Sales**(Product Code,No Customer, amount, Id sale)
>
> **Customer** ( No Customer, Name, Adress, Phone, town)
>
> **Products** (Product Code, Description, Price)

Well, my question is, how do I do this query in MySQL? :

Name of the customers who purchased all the products.

I have only this query that joins me the two tables that I have to use:

> Select Name from Customer join Sales using(No Customer);

But I have the question, how do I separate the Customers that have all the products purchased?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: who purchased all the different products ?

Comment: Where's your table for the Products?

Comment: Questions asking for code should **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called relational division.It gets the result using contradiction.This is called classical method.

```
     select c.name from customer c where not exists
(select * from products p where not exists
(select * from sales s where p.productcode=s.productcode and c.nocustomer=s.nocustomer))
```

There is one more way to do these type of queries.It was invented a few years back and published in a research paper which claimed that the new way was much more faster than the classical way.I will quote the source soon.The new method is using group by and count(*) like this:

```
    select c.customername from customer c,sales s,product p 
where p.productcode=s.productcode and c.nocustomer=s.nocustomer 
group by s.nocustomer having count(*)=
(select count(distinct p1.productcode) from product p1)
```

The above query just compares the count of products bought by customer with the total count of distinct products in the products table and returns the name of the customers who matches the criteria.On a personal note I like the classical method more than this but the new method has a much more fast response then the classical method and I have checked it myself.Hope it helps.